# Why am I obtaining these warning messages into the page of an old Joomla website?

Tags: php, apache, joomla, xampp, joomla3.0

I am not so into **PHP** and I have the following problem.

I reinstalled an old Joomla website (it is an old version of the CMS that I have to upgrade) on my local server (**XAMPP**).

The problem is that now I obtain some warning message like this into the pages:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\erusma\plugins\content\embed_google_docs_viewer\embed_google_docs_viewer.php on line 61
```

The website works fine but somewhere I have these warning. I think that maybe is something related to the PHP log settings or something like this.

What can I do to avoid these links? (I can't change the code)

Comment: Dude, come on. It's literally a google search away...

Comment: Can you show code of your embed_google_docs_viewer.php file?

Comment: can you Show the Line 61, mybe you have a reference with depracted & in the line.

Comment: Since you can't modify the code and the error message explains the issue in the code, this is a question about how to use Joomla not a question about coding.  Better to ask it on the Joomla Stackexchange site [joomla.se], the joomla documentation etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few options (listed in increasing level of difficulty):

- Ignore the warning messages as they are likely doing no harm especially on local host.
- Suppress the warning messages via the appropriate option in Joomla Global Configuration and/or directives in php.ini or .htaccess files.
- Downgrade PHP to an earlier version.
- Upgrade Joomla / third party extensions to later versions.
- Fix the code.